# Python iterating - problems finding the product of digits in a string

Tags: python, loops, iterator

Trying to iterate through a number string in python and print the product of the first 5 numbers,then the second 5, then the third 5, etc etc.  Unfortunately, I just keep getting the product of the first five digits over and over.  Eventually I'll append them to a list.  Why is my code stuck?

edit:  Original number is an integer so I have to make it a string

```
def product_of_digits(number):
        d= str(number)
        for integer in d:
            s = 0
            k = []
            while s < (len(d)):
                print (int(d[s])*int(d[s+1])*int(d[s+2])*int(d[s+3])*int(d[s+4]))
            s += 1

    print (product_of_digits(a))
```

Comment: Because the indentation is wrong.  Shift `s += 1` _to the right_ so that it's inside the `while` loop.

Comment: When you say "read the second 5", you mean 2 to 6, or 6 to 10?

Comment: And don't forget to change the condition in `while`.  You can't read beyond the size of the list which is what would happen.  [Accessing index `s+4` if `s=len(d)-1`...]

Comment: I do this for my own amusement :)  No grades!

Comment: I recommend learning about the [`for` loop](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). It's much less bug-prone than a `while` with a manually-incremented counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1) Your `s+=1` indentation is incorrect
2) It should be `s+=5` instead (assuming you want products of 1-5, 6-10, 11-15 and so on otherwise s+=1 is fine)

```
def product_of_digits(number):
    d = str(number)
    s = 0
    while s < (len(d)-5):
        print (int(d[s])*int(d[s+1])*int(d[s+2])*int(d[s+3])*int(d[s+4]))
        s += 5 (see point 2)

print (product_of_digits(124345565534))
```

Comment: Thanks!  I did mean 1-5, 2-6, 3-7 etc.  This worked perfectly.  Not sure when moved that out of the loop ><

Answer (score 2):

Let me list out the mistakes in the program.

1. You are iterating over `d` for nothing. You don't need that.
2. `s += 1` is not part of the while loop. So, `s` will never get incremented, leading to infinite loop.
3. `print (product_of_digits(a))` is inside the function itself, where `a` is not defined.
4. To find the product of all the consecutive 5 numbers, you cannot loop till the end of `d`. So, the loop should have been `while s <= (len(d)-5):`
5. You have initialized `k`, but used it nowhere.

So, the corrected program looks like this

```
def product_of_digits(number):
    d, s = str(number), 0
    while s <= (len(d)-5):
        print(int(d[s]) * int(d[s+1]) * int(d[s+2]) * int(d[s+3]) * int(d[s+4]))
        s += 1

product_of_digits(123456)
```

**Output**

```
120
720
```

You can also use a for loop, like this

```
def product_of_digits(number):
    d = str(number)
    for s in range(len(d) - 4):
        print(int(d[s]) * int(d[s+1]) * int(d[s+2]) * int(d[s+3]) * int(d[s+4]))
```

Comment: I needed to turn the integer into a string, that's what the d is for.  Thanks- I moved s+= 1 over and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

numpy.product([int(i) for i in str(s)])

where s is the number.